# I want to edit a macro such that the data from the 1 to another Sheet by matching date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to edit a macro which copies data fro the sub-sheets IOSRef, AndroidRef, WebRef, BetaRe to a main Sheet (all belong to a single worksheet). BUT I want it to match the dates first and accordingly copy the data.

---

I've tried to create an array of dates of the main sheet and match it with the 7 day date range in the sub sheets and put it in a loop. And thus created 4 such loops which are visible in the code.
The script runs without any error but does not perform any action.

---

```
function UpdateMacro() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);

 var data=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,1,321); 
//Date array named data //

  for(var nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++){ 
    if (data[0][nn]==spreadsheet.getRange('IOSRef!B2')){
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(data[i][nn]); 
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('IOSRef'), true);
// Above 3 lines for copying the data //
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('IOSRef!B3:I6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);      
    }
    else{spreadsheet.setCurrentCell('NULL');};
      }; //to Copy from iOS to Consolidated 

  for(var nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++){
    if (data[0][nn]==spreadsheet.getRange('AndroidRef!B2')){
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(data[i][nn]);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(5, 0).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('AndroidRef'), true);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 1, 4, 8).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('AndroidRef!B3:I6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);     
    };
      }; //to Copy from Android to Consolidated 

  for(var nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++){
    if (data[0][nn]==spreadsheet.getRange('WebRef!B2')){
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(data[i][nn]);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(9, 0).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('WebRef'), true);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 1, 4, 8).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('WebRef!B3:I6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);     
    };
      }; //to Copy from Web to Consolidated

    for(var nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++){
    if (data[0][nn]==spreadsheet.getRange('BetaRef!B2')){
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(data[i][nn]);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(13, 0).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('BetaRef'), true);
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(2, 1, 4, 8).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('BetaRef!B3:I6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);     
    };
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line: `var data=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,1,321);`

There is no data.length because it returns a range.

Perhaps you would prefer to add `.getValues()` to the end

However, even then the data.length is always going to be one so do you really want to use a for loop?

In this line: `spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(data[i][nn]);`

you're using the index `i` which is not defined in our example  so this is not a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because `i` is not defined for us, so we can't really help.

Also consider this code:

`spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated'), true);
 var data=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,1,321);`

The macro recorder follows your actions, so when you move to another sheet and get data it records all of your movements.  But in a script you don't need to move to another sheet.  So the above lines of script could be written simply as:

`var data=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Consolidated').getRange(2,1,1,321);` thus avoid all the extra code of activating sheets that don't need to be activated.